# Shoutem UI NavigationBar Wrap Icon with Button Changes Style

Tags: screen

```
     <Screen>
    <ImageBackground 
        source={ require('./images/surface.jpg')}
        style={{ width: 375, height: 70 }} >
      <NavigationBar
        styleName="clear" leftComponent={<Icon name="sidebar" />}
        centerComponent={<Image source={require('./images/logo.png') }></Image>}
        rightComponent={<Icon name="social-wall" />}/>
    </ImageBackground>
  </Screen>
```

[image: Before adding button]

The image above is what I want in my header.  I want the sidebar icon to be changed to a button just retain the same style.  However, when I wrap the icon with a button, the icon changes to dark.  How do I configure it to remain light.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the button a `styleName="secondary"`, this changes it to the secondary style defined in `theme.js`. The secondary style uses a dark background color (not visible in your use case due to it being nested in a `navigationBar`) and light text.

```
<Button styleName="secondary">
  <Icon name="social-wall" />
</Button>
```